# Pagination Links for Custom post type returns 404

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, pagination, paginate-links

first of all, I am new to WP development, and PHP.
I am developing a template that has several custom post types. the problem is when I add pagination to my custom post type, all pagination links return 404.
this is how I register custom post type:

```
function custom_post_projects()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Projects', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Project', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('New Project', 'book'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Project'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Project'),
        'new_item' => __('New Project'),
        'all_items' => __('All Projects'),
        'view_item' => __('View Project'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Projects'),
        'not_found' => __('No Projects found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Projects found in the Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Project:'),
        'menu_name' => 'Projects'
    );
    $args = array(
        'has_archive' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'description' => 'Holds our projects and project specific data',
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'project', 'pages' => true)

    );
    register_post_type('project', $args);
   
}
add_action('init', 'custom_post_projects');
```

This is my archive-project.php

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; // If we have a 'paged' parameter, set $paged to that value, if not set it to 1

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'project',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'paged' => $paged, // Our current paged parameter set above.
    'order' => 'desc',
    'orderby' => 'date',
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<div id="container">
    <div id="portfolio_content">
        <div id="portfolio_wrap">
            <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()):
                $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                <span class="title">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </span><br>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php
            $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
            echo paginate_links(
                array(
                    'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
                    'format' => 'page/%#%',
                    'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
                    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
                )
            );
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**my problem is**

the following links don't work

foo.com/project/page/2

page/2 works on normal posts but for every custom post type it returns a 404

foo.com/project/page/1 works fine and navigates to foo.com/project.

I have tried the following already:

1. flashing permalinks
2. Changing permalinks to something else and flashing it
3. Adding  flush_rewrite_rules(true); to function.php
4. Disabling the Theme and enabling it
5. Deactivating all plugins.
6. Deleting all Cache

Can someone please guide me in the right direction as I was not able to find any solution on web. I have tried all the answers on stackExchange.

**Updated:**
Based On Fuxia's comment
I changed the code as follow and it works like a charm
The issue was the main query was not able to find the page.

this is updated archive-project.php

```
<?php
get_header();
?>

<div id="container">
    <div id="portfolio_content">
        <div id="portfolio_wrap">
            <?php if (have_posts()):
                while (have_posts()):
                    the_post(); ?>
                    <span class="title">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </span><br>
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

            <?php
            $big = 999999999; // Need an unlikely integer
            echo paginate_links(
                array(
                    'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
                    'format' => 'page/%#%',
                    'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
                    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
                )
            );
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
get_footer();
```

also added the following to function.php

```
 function custom_modify_main_query($query)
{
    if (is_post_type_archive('project') && !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        $posts_per_page = get_option('posts_per_page');
        $query->set('posts_per_page', $posts_per_page);
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_modify_main_query');
```

Comment: Your mistake is that you are creating a new query. But there is already a main query initiated by WordPress after the URL is parsed. And if that main query doesn't find a post, then you get a 404. Filter `pre_get_posts` instead, and alter the main query. Use our search, you will find many good examples.

Comment: Your answer worked

Comment: Can you please add answer to this question

Comment: Glad it worked. :) I'm just closing it as duplicate to link to a post with good reference code. No need to repeat that here.